# Can't consume a SSL protected webservice with Java/Glassfish

Tags: java, ssl, service, glassfish

I'm trying to consume a Webservice hosted under https security.

I'm using Java and glassfish and I'm getting the following error:

INFO: HTTP transport error: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: java.security.cert.CertificateException: No name matching testdomain.com found

The thing is that this specific server is used for testing and it's using the production certificate (the one with CN=domain.com)

I already added the domain.com certificate to my glassfish domain's cacerts keystore using keytool -importcert and it didn't work.

I also tried creating a self signed certificate with the CN=testdomain.com and adding it to the cacerts keystore and it didn't work either...

So how do I configure Java/Glassfish to consume this Web Service?

Answer (score 1):

The CN of the server certificate should match the domain in URL to which the client connects. If still doesn't work, I would check if the IP maps to this hostname too (reverse DNS). It is the client, who verifies it. If you want to bypass this hostname verification, see the example code in my article: http://jakubneubauer.wordpress.com/2011/09/06/java-webservice-over-ssl/

The priciple is that you provide your own HostnameVerifier to the service client proxy.

Answer (score 0):

THe self-signed certificate needs to be installed in the keystore *of the Web service,* along with its private key, and imported into the truststore *of Glassfish.*

Answer (score -1):

the self signed certificate needs to be installed in key store of your java client. and testdomain.com should be resolved using dns.

Comment: The client has nothing to do with it. In this case Glassfish is the client. Your second comment is pointless: domains *are* resolved via DNS.